# Image Processing using MPI

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

I have to do some image processing using parallel programming. I'm using Python with MPI (mpi4py).
I have two functions, Sepia and Flip. I think they are self explanatory. This is the sequential code:

```
def sepia(name):
  img = Image.open('dog.jpg')
  for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
      r, g, b = img.getpixel((i, j))
      rr = int(r * 0.393 + g * 0.769 + b * 0.189)
      gg = int(r * 0.349 + g * 0.686 + b * 0.168)
      bb = int(r * 0.272 + g * 0.534 + b * 0.131)
      img.putpixel((i,j),(rr,gg,bb))
  img.save(name)

def flip(name):
  img = Image.open('dog.jpg')
  white = (255,255,255)
  image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
  for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
      r, g, b = img.getpixel((i,j))
      image.putpixel((width-i-1, height-j-1),(r,g,b))
  image.save(name)
```

How can I parallelize this code using MPI?

Comment: Does it have to be with MPI? you can get good speed by using numpy\opencv

Comment: I have to do a project for school involving parallel computing, it does not have to be neceserally MPI. I have to mention I am not accustomed with opencv.

Comment: You need to write more code to get help here, to show how you want to structure your MPI program (and read up on how the basics are done).  Conceptually each mpi process fires the same program, and you need to spread the pixels in your program out to each process, and let each process iterate over its share of pixels.  For the first function that is easy, for the second you have to take into account that pixel(i-1) might be in another process.